# Multiple profiles in firefox using one sync account

Tags: firefox, profile, account

Can you synchronize multiple Firefox profiles using the same email? My main goal is divide work and home bookmarks, using the same Sync account.

At the present time, if I create a new profile called 'Work' and entered my email, firefox download all bookmarks from my profile 'default', but I want a distinct content in each profile at the Firefox Cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, Firefox always links 1 profile to 1 sync account.

I would recommend you to create a second Firefox profile and use one for work and one for private use. This would also clearly separate data like history, ... which you don't sync.

See [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) for instructions: